# No result using makeStyles Material UI in react 18

Tags: javascript, java, c#, php, reactjs

**Hi Im exploring ReactJs and Material UI and Im following outdated tutorials. I having a problem with this material UI makestyles how do I use this? This is the format that Im using and there are no results. As you see I update the material UI import too**

styles.js

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/material/styles";
    
    export default makeStyles(() => ({
      appBar: {
        borderRadius: 15,
        margin: "30px 0",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      },
      heading: {
        color: "rgba(0,183,255, 1)",
      },
      image: {
        marginLeft: "15px",
      },
    }));
```

App.js

```
import useStyles from "./styles";
    
    const App = () => {
      const classes = useStyles();
    
      return (
        <Container maxwidth="lg">
          <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
            <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align="center">
              Memories
            </Typography>
            <img
              className={classes.image}
              src={memories}
              alt="memories"
              height="60"
```

Well I can use style inside a file but I want to make a style in another file like style.js to make it more cleaner.

```
const App = () => {
  // const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container maxwidth="lg">
      <AppBar
        style={{
          borderRadius: 15,
          margin: "30px 0",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
        position="static"
        color="inherit"
      >
        <Typography variant="h2" align="center">
          Memories
        </Typography>
        <img src={memories} alt="memories" height="60" />
      </AppBar>
```

Comment: I also discover routing should I use that for styling?

Answer (score 4):

## This will definitely solve your problem!

**styles.js**

```
 
    ❌import { makeStyles } from "@mui/material/styles"; // <--- delete this ❌

    import { styled } from "@mui/system"; // <--- Add this ✅

    ❌export default makeStyles(() => ({ //  <--- delete this ❌

    export default styled(()=>({ // <--- Add this ✅

      appBar: {
        borderRadius: 15,
        margin: "30px 0",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      },
      heading: {
        color: "rgba(0,183,255, 1)",
      },
      image: {
        marginLeft: "15px",
      },
    }));
```

**Reason**:

The *@mui/styles* package is not compatible with **React 18**, as shown in the documentation - [Documentation](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/). 
You should migrate to either *@mui/system* and use **styled()**, **sx**, etc,
Documentation for sx  props > [SX Props Docs MUI](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)

```
sx props -> property is used like inline styling.
for example : 
 <Box
        sx={{
          bgcolor: 'background.paper',
          boxShadow: 1,
          borderRadius: 2,
          p: 2,
          minWidth: 300,
        }}
      >
    
 </Box>
```

or *migrate* to **tss-react**

which has an API which is **closer** to *@mui/styles* . 
I hope this explanation helps other who may come to this issue.

Comment: This solved my problem with React 18.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I have edited

Answer (score 1):

styles.js

```
    import { makeStyles } from "@mui/material/styles";
    
    export const useStyles =  makeStyles(() => ({
      appBar: {
        borderRadius: 15,
        margin: "30px 0",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      },
      heading: {
        color: "rgba(0,183,255, 1)",
      },
      image: {
        marginLeft: "15px",
      },
    }));
```

Comment: this what I got..

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR


src\styles.js
  Line 3:16:  'useStyles' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0):

```
import {styled } from "@mui/material";

const useStyles = styled((theme) => ({
  toolbarMargin: {
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar
  }
}));

const Header = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>
          <h1>Brand Name</h1>
          <Button variant="contained" color="error" sx={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>
            Connect Wallet
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: With React18 this is the new way to use styled component. I also face issue. 
Please check latest document of material ui v5.6.4. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#usescrolltrigger-options-trigger

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This 100% does not work.

Comment: @ANKITAGARWAL - I think styled should be imported form "@mui/system". Also, the link that you provided to the react-app-bar doesn't point to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**@mui/styles** no longer works in **React 18**.

Try this:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

export default styled(()=>({
  appBar: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: "30px 0",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  heading: {
    color: "rgba(0,183,255, 1)",
  },
  image: {
    marginLeft: "15px",
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import `makeStyles` from `tss-react` instead of from `MUI`

According to: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32881#issuecomment-1135051663