# Which Material UI feature can be used instead of makeStyles() that is compatible with React 18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently working on a React project where I've been using Material-UI's makeStyles() function for styling my components. However, I recently learned that makeStyles() is not compatible with React 18's concurrent mode.

I'm looking for an alternative feature in Material-UI that provides similar functionality to makeStyles(), but is compatible with React 18. Ideally, this feature would allow me to define styles in a similar way to makeStyles(), and would also allow me to access theme values directly.

Here's an example of how I'm currently using makeStyles():

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Typography className={classes.root}>{data.title}</Typography>;
}
```

Can anyone suggest a suitable replacement for makeStyles() that works with React 18?

I've been using inline styles and the makeStyles() function from Material-UI to style my components in my React application.I was expecting to continue using makeStyles() and inline styles for my styling needs. However, I recently learned that makeStyles() is not compatible with React 18's concurrent mode, which I plan to use in my project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71948818/no-result-using-makestyles-material-ui-in-react-18

Comment: When I migrated from v4 to v5 of Material-UI, I converted all of my `makeStyles/useStyles` usages to tss-react (https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migrating-from-jss/#2-use-tss-react). There's a codemod (which I wrote) to help with automatically converting most `makeStyles` usage patterns.